# For $H$ normal subgroup of $G$, given $K\leq G/H$, is $H$ still a normal subgroup of $\bigcup_{x\in K}x$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

The reason I'd like to ask this question is that. Intuitively we regard quotient groups as some weaker structural version for the original group. So it would be natural to ask that, after we know what $G/H$ and its subgroups looks like, we want to rebuild what $G$ and some of its subgroups look like.
So here's the question: For $H$ normal subgroup of $G$, given $K\leq G/H$, is $H$ still a normal subgroup of $\bigcup_{x\in K}x$? where $G/H$ denotes the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: Subgroup $K\leq G/H$ corresponds with subgroup $KH\leq G$. Do you mean to ask whether $H$ is a normal subgroup of $KH$? If so then the answer is yes. If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then automatically it is a normal subgroup of every subgroup of $G$ that contains $H$ as a subgroup.

Comment: Please put the entire question in the body. That will also allow you to spend a bit more space on the actual objects involved (at present, it seems like the final object mentioned makes no sense, as you take a union of things that are not sets in any natural way).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Since $K$ is a subset of $G/H$, it is a set of cosets, so the union is certainly meaningful. However the question is trivial: $K=X/H$ for some subgroup $X$ of $G$ containing $H$ and $\bigcup K=X$. Since $H$ is normal in $G$, it is obviously normal in $X$.

Comment: @egreg Good point. I am just so used to not really thinking of quotients as made up of cosets that I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union you're mentioning makes sense if you think to $G/H$ as the set of (left) cosets with respect to $H$.

However, the correspondence theorem (or whatever you call it) says that $K$ is of the form $X/H$, for a unique subgroup $X$ of $G$, with $H\subseteq G$. Then
$$
\bigcup_{x\in K}x=X
$$
and of course $H$ is normal in $X$, being normal in $G$.

Comment: Indeed, what I meant for $G/H$ is the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$.
But how do we know that $K$ is of the form $X/H$, derived from $K\leq 
 G/H$?

Comment: @TaylorHuang That's a well known property.

Comment: Alright, thanks though.
I've figured out some way actually. It comes with a lemma that
If $H\leq H_1 \leq G$, and $H$ is normal in $G$, then $H$ is normal in $H_1$. Following that, given $K\leq G/H$, we know that $H\leq\bigcup_{x\in K}x\leq G$, since H is normal in $G$, it'd be normal in $H_1$.